# Rows of dataTable disappear after adding data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I use jquery ajax to add a data which shows on dataTable.
And when i add, everything works fine, but the rows of dataTable disappear  [image: disappearing rows] and recovers after refreshing the page.

What could it be related to?

The Code i use for ajax requests:

```
showInPopup = (url, title) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (res) {
            $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
            $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
            $('#form-modal').modal('show');
        }
    })
}

jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.isValid) {
                    $('#view-all').html(res.html)
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                    $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                    $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                }
                else
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
         
        return false;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}

$('#form-modal').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This logic may be inverted: `if (res.isValid) {`.  How are you exercising `form()`?

Comment: Are you using datatables? If yes, you need to reinitialize the table

Comment: Could you please show the view part and how you use the datatable?